# A different twist on the aggregation of calculated measures in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, aggregation

I have to count something in a strange way, and it works in most cases -- both at leaves and at higher levels of aggregation across multiple dimensions. But it doesn't give correctly aggregated values for one specific dimension.

What I have at the moment is ...

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Active Commitments]
 AS NULL,
FORMAT_STRING = '#,#', 
VISIBLE = 1;    

SCOPE (DESCENDANTS([Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy],,AFTER));     
[Measures].[Active Commitments] =
iif([Constituent Activity].[Type].currentMember.Properties("Name")="Correspondence",
    sum(([Commitment Dates].[Start Date], NULL: [Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy]), [Measures].[Commitment Count]),
    sum(([Commitment Dates].[First Funded Date], NULL: [Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy]), [Measures].[Commitment Count]))
        - sum(([Commitment Dates].[Stop Date],[Commitment].[Was Commitment Ever Active].[Sometime Active], NULL: [Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy]),  [Measures].[Commitment Count]); 
END SCOPE;

SCOPE (DESCENDANTS([Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy],,AFTER));
<Similar to above>
```

As you can see, the complexity is that one type of "commitment" commences at the `[Start Date]` and others commence at the `[First Funded Date]`.

This fails whenever multiple members of `[Constituent Activity]` are selected because in such cases the use of `currentMember` in the SCOPE statement is invalid. For example, the following MDX executes successfully but outputs `#Error` --

```
select  
    [Measures].[Active Commitments] on columns
    ,[Date Dimension].[Fiscal Year Hierarchy].[Fiscal Year].&[2011\12] on rows
from Compass3
where
    {[Constituent Activity].[Description].[XYZ]
    ,[Constituent Activity].[Description].[ABC]}
```

I think what I need to encode within the SCOPE statement is the recursive ...

```
if a single member of [Constituent Activity] is current
then use the calc as defined above
else use [Measures].[Active Commitments] = sum(all selected members of [Constituent Activity], [Measures].[Active Commitments])
```

... but how would I write that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have control all the way back to the data warehouse/data source view? Can you add a calculated field to your fact table, so you have [Commitment Active Date] at the cell level? Then you could do much simpler counts in the cube.

I have found that enforcing business rules and doing business calculations in the data warehouse is more efficient and easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Bill. I do have control over that but it is an established cube that I inherited and have tried to any changes as close to the surface as possible to avoid unwanted side effects. The current structure for handling dates is quite complex and so adding another date is tricky.